# Fetch ETH USD Rate from past using Oracle

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, oracles

Is it possible to fetch the USD rate of ETH at a specific time in the past to a smart contract from an external API using an oracle? i.e. I have a function which tracks whether `now > start + 10 days`. Now, if this statement is true, then it should fetch the ETH USD value at the exact time of start + 10 days.

Comment: You can always create a custom oracle which preprocesses data any way you wish.

Comment: How would I go about fetching eth value at a specific time from an api?

Comment: Two ways 1) You create an Oracle API that takes parameter "when" 2) Oracle regularly feeds the exchange rate to the blockchain smart contract which has getAt(now - 10 days) function that can look to the history. What is better approach is hard to tell without understanding the big picture.